# Is there a way to shorten this variable definition?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I currently have this type of deceleration:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, DateTime>>>();
```

The problem is it's getting too long to type out:

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, DateTime>>> getDictionaryDifferences(Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, DateTime>>> d1, Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, DateTime>>> d2)
```

How do I make this a type or something other than a class that needs a defined constructor? How could I shorten this notation?

Comment: Why "other than a class"? You could override Dictionary<> with your own class that's specifically that type of dictionary.

Comment: Well if I implement a class I think it will get bloated with override information... I idealy want something short and clean. So I can say MyDictionary... Kinda like a struct in C.

Comment: The bigger problem you have now is understanding what that <,<<,>>> variable is, and how its supposed to be used. I like Tuples, and they have a place, but too many of them and other loose/utility types and it becomes increasingly hard to follow/maintain.

Comment: Yeah so you handle that by defining what it is in one place and documenting the values... Idealy you'd want to have a class and name all the values but that becomes difficult when working with two different sources of information. I.e. I have objects in my db and objects in my application and their models aren't the same... So I could create another class for the two.. I can't change the models.. Life of legacy software..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
public class MyClass : Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, DateTime>>>
{}
```

and then:

```
var myDictionary = new MyClass();

public static MyClass getDictionaryDifferences(MyClass d1, MyClass d2)
```

Comment: Exactly... no need to override a bunch of stuff. You don't have to override anything.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't be better than that

Answer (score 4):

Another option is a [using alias directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx#Anchor_3) at the top of the file

```
using SpecialDictionary = Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, DateTime>>>;
```

And then you can do

```
var dictionary = new SpecialDictionary();
```

and

```
public static SpecialDictionary getDictionaryDifferences(
    SpecialDictionary d1, 
    SpecialDictionary d2)
```

Comment: Do you know anything about the advantages and disadvantages of this compared to defining a class?

Comment: I'd say the main disadvantage is that you have to put the using directive in all files where you want to use it.

Comment: A disadvantage to the class that inherits is that your code would not work with the base dictionary class anymore or any other potential classes that would inherit from it, unless you define explicit casts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not too "tied" to the structure of individual tuples, you could use generics and make your method applicable to dictionaries of lists of other kinds:

```
public static Dictionary<K,List<V>> GetDictionaryDifferences<K,V>(
    IDictionary<K,List<V>> d1
,   IDictionary<K,List<V>> d2
) {
    ...
}
```

This would let you implement the algorithm once, without requiring dictionary keys to be strings, and without not knowing that `V` is a `Tuple<,>` of some kind.

Comment: This definitely has its place! My types are a little more specific than what I've described, but I'll keep this in mind. Thank you